# Clustering of individuals based on their time spent at various points of interest

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, jaccard-similarity, frequent-itemsets

Consider a set of individuals, denoted by $\mathcal{I}$, and a set of points of interest (POIs), denoted by $\mathcal{J}$ (with $|\mathcal{I} | \approx 10^4$ and $|\mathcal{J} | \leq 50$).

For each individual $i \in \mathcal{I}$, we know the time spent at POI $j \in \mathcal{J}$, denoted by $a_{i,j} \geq 0$. We do not impose any constraints on $\sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} a_{i,j}$ for any individual $i$.

I would like to find patterns that coherently group people based on individual time spent at each point of interest. What are meaningful methods to do so?

I thought of converting time spent into binary indicators such as $\mathcal{1}_{a_{i,j} \geq \alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is some suitable threshold. This would allow me to apply frequent itemset mining (such as FP-Growth), or, based on some meaningful distance measure like Jaccard similarity, some community detection approach (e.g., Leiden algorithm).

However, I was wondering whether there are some 'direct' approaches that would not require calculating a binary indicator first. More generally, I'd be grateful for any helpful hints or recommendations (e.g., regarding the suitability of the two approaches sketched out above).